# ngx-socket-io ng test "NullInjectorError: No provider for WrappedSocket!"

Tags: angular

I using ngx-socket-io and it's working fine in development. But I'm having a problem when I run the  `ng test`.

It gives me error `NullInjectorError: No provider for WrappedSocket!`

Here is my `spec.ts`

```
const IO_CONFIG:SocketIoConfig = {url:'http://localhost:3000,options:{}}
  
describe(...,()=>{
  beforeEach(()=>{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports:[
       ...
       SocketIoModule.forRoot(IO_CONFIG)
       ...
     ]
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: `SocketIoModule.forRoot(....)`, try adding that in the `imports` section of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`. You should know what goes in the `...`.

Comment: Could you solve the issue? I am currently having that same issue.

Answer (score 2):

try to add this code to "imports"
`SocketIoModule.forRoot({ url: environment.apiUrl, options: { transports: ['websocket'], reconnection: true } })`

Comment: Just to point out a detail here.  adding `transports: ['websocket'], reconnection: true` to the options of `config` (or in his case, `IO_CONFIG`) is what fixed it for me.